# Sails API doesnt send all object's attributes to front end Angular app

Tags: angularjs, api, object, attributes, sails.js

I am creating an object from my backend sails API to send to my angular front app.

The object is created like this :

```
   getHommeAndChevre: function (req, res) {
      // console.log(req.param("id"));
      Trophe.find({foot: req.param('id')}, function(err, trophes){
        if(!trophes) {return res.status(400).end();}
        if(trophes){
          _.each(trophes, function(trophe, index){
            User.find(trophe.id, function(err, user){
              // console.log(user);
              if (trophe.trophe == 0) {var chevre = trophe; chevre.picture = user.picture; chevre.name = user.first_name; };
              if (trophe.trophe == 1) {var homme = trophe; homme.picture = user.picture; homme.name = user.first_name;};
              if (index == trophes.length - 1)
                return res.status(200).json({chevre: chevre, homme: homme});
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

The problem is that the objects `chevre` or `homme` I get back on the front-end don't include a `picture` attribute & a `name` attribute as I am specifying in my function here :

```
 if (trophe.trophe == 0) {var chevre = trophe; chevre.picture = user.picture; chevre.name = user.first_name; };
                  if (trophe.trophe == 1) {var homme = trophe; homme.picture = user.picture; homme.name = user.first_name;};
```

Here is the object I get back on the front end side [image]

As you can see there is no `picture` and `name` attribute in my homme object !

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<model>.findOne()` if you're looking for a single record.

`<model>.find()` always returns an `Array`, so when you do `User.find(trophe.id, function(err, user){}`, user.first_name will be `undefined`. Instead, you would to use `user[0].first_name`.

So then you might have:

```
homme : {
    name : undefined
}
```

Which is then stringified (see [sails docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/res-json)) by sending it into `res.json()`. At that point, it is likely removed:

```
sails> var trophe = {name : undefined}
undefined
sails> trophe
{ name: undefined }
sails> JSON.stringify(trophe)
'{}'
sails>
```